# Passing additional error message to validation error bag on auth

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication

I am using the RegisterController that comes by default in Laravel. It has a default validator in it, however, I want to return additional message inside it, so that I can know which form it was to re-open associated modal.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator =  Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    $messages = $validator->errors();
    $messages->add('registerError', 'Custom Message');

    return $validator;
}
```

I tried this however couldn't figure out how to return `$messages`, as there is a `validate()` function right after this returned validator result:

```
$this->validator($request->all())->validate();
```

What is the proper way of sending `'registerError'` to the view together with the other validator errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple forms on a single page you can use named error bags. Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views).

In your `RegisterController` replace this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    // rest of the register method code here...
}
```

With this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator, 'register');
    }

    // rest of the register method code here...
}
```

Then you can catch it in your view like so:

```
@if ($errors->register->any())
    // open the modal
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. Using this approach, I couldn't catch it using `$errors->has('register')` in my blade. What is the proper way of achieving it?

Comment: Updated the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks. I made it work for the register. However, now I couldn't get the rest for some reason. How should I access the default errors now? `$errors->has('username')` doesn't work now, for example. How can I access username now?

Comment: Look at the documentation that I've linked to in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some few changes to your code below, on how to properly add and return errors with your validator instance

```
protected function validator(array $data)
 {
    $validator =  Validator::make($data, [
             'name' => 'required|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
             'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

   return $validator;
```

}

Then in your controller method

```
   $validator = $this->validator($this->request->all());

   if($validator->fails()){

      $validator->errors()->add('registerError', 'Custom Message'); 

      return View::make('myview')->withErrors($validator);

    } else {
      // Do something else you want to do 
   }
```